# Is it possible to use latest OWASP CRS rules in CloudArmor

Tags: google-cloud-armor

CloudArmor appears to use OWASP CRS 3.0.1 rules which are now pretty dated (last update around 4 years ago). CRS is now on V3.3 and V3.4 is in development.

Is there a way to take the new rules from coreruleset Github Repo and import into CloudArmor? Does Google have plans to update to the newer set by default?

Main driver is that some of the rules are very dated or unworkable. For example scanner detection triggers on "python-requests" as a User-Agent and this is no longer checked for in latest V3.3 ruleset.

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible. I believe the OWASP module is compiled and importing is not supported.

Comment: In GCP's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rule-tuning) they already have provided a link for a [GIthub Repo](https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/tree/v3.0/master) for CRS v3.4.

Comment: @BryanL - Where in the documentation does it show how to load the CRS v3.4 rules? Your links do not provide that information.

Answer (score 0):

If this has not been solved yet: I think Google does not give you the chance to pick for yourself.
Also, it's a commercial support question that should probably be directed there.